# react-table - exclude column from useGlobalFilter

Tags: react-table

I'm using the `useGlobalFilter` hook of [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table), and it's working like a charm.

However I have one question I cannot figure out using the [docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useGlobalFilter.md):

**How can I exclude a column from being inlcuded within `useGlobalFilter`?**

Answer (score 0):

In the Column object passed to the columns option in useTable(), add this line for each corresponding column that you want to exclude from useGlobalFilter:

```
disableGlobalFilter: true
```